# CMake: How to run a add_custom_command before everything else

Tags: cmake

I have a custom command

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT config.h
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mk_config_h.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h
)
```

I'm trying to run it before everything else and I generate unix Makefiles.

However PRE_BUILD is only supported for VS2010 which means that `config.h` is build before linking.

how do I make a custom command before cmake starts compiling sources.

Comment: Is the output file from your custom command (i.e. config.h) used as a source file in another CMake target (i.e. in the list of sources passed via `add_executable` or `add_library`)?  If so, you shouldn't need to worry about the execution order - CMake will invoke the custom command as and when required.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You should use [`add_custom_target`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_target) instead and [`add_dependencies`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_dependencies) to make your normal target depend on it:

```
add_custom_target(
    myCustomTarget
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mk_config_h.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h
)
add_dependencies(myTarget myCustomTarget)
```

This should ensure that the command is run before compiling the sources of `myTarget`.

Comment: It took me a while that add_custom_target is much better for running an executable than add_custom_command. Thank you for that solution!

Comment: @Anonymous - No, its not better. It has significant drawback, it ALWAYS runs as described in documentation (The target has no output file and is *always considered out of date* even if the commands try to create a file with the name of the target), even if dependency does not change.

Comment: Using `add_custom_target` and `add_dependencies` as suggested by @Simon worked for me, to force some header and library files from another build to be copied before my normal target builds.  I had previously tried to use `add_custom_command( ... PRE_BUILD ... )`, but it would not execute in the correct order.

Comment: I'm finding that this fails in parallel builds, if the custom target takes a long time to finish. Later build stages will run in the right order, but will use the incompletely-written output files. I have not yet figured out how to force run-to-completion.

Comment: @Linas, same issue with Ninja, unable to figure out. But, I have no problems with Makefile since I added the trick explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31518137/1729117

Answer (score 3):

Usualy build systems which are based on makefiles do not need to mention headers as part of a target. Further more, adding headers to target is considered to be an antipattern. But generating a header is an exception from this rule.

http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2013/03/26/a-list-of-common-cmake-antipatterns/

You should set your `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h` as part of some other compilled target.
For example:

```
set(PROGRAM1_SOURCES main_program1.cpp)
set(PROGRAM1_HEADERS main_program1.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h)
add_executable(program1 ${PROGRAM1_SOURCES} ${PROGRAM1_HEADERS})
```

So that, CMake will know which target actually needs the generated `config.h` and will be able to insert the generation commands into a right build steps.

Also, see an example at https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/#s5

Comment: You need headers if you want code analysis from the various IDEs to work.

Comment: @zerophase, I agree. Project-files for IDE often need reference to all files of the project. But cmake is able to build the project without header files.

Comment: Oh for sure. Just usually headers end up having to be added in to support different end users.