# cmake add_custom_command that is executed on every build

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I want to have something in CMake that will be executed whenever I enter make

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build_date.cc
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mk_build_date.py 
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build_date.cc
)
add_custom_target(build-date-xxx 
                  ALL
                  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build_date.cc)
```

thats what I'm currently doing. unfortunately `make build-date-xxx` will generate the file only once.

even without the `add_custom_target` declaration the file is only build once.

the result should be something like this in GNU Make

```
.PHONY all: 
    echo "hallo welt"
all: foo.c bar.c
%.c:
    touch $@
```

in that makefile whenever make is entered. since all is the first target it will always be invoked and the custom command `echo "hallo welt"` is actually executed.

Comment: closely related but executes too late: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920072/cmake-always-run-command-regardless-of-any-dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET and use the argument ALL in it.
Then make your main target dependent on this custom target.

Comment: actually thats exactly what I do look at the second command in cmake. It generates the file once cmake is run. but not everytime make is run.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your order... have a custom target *with no dependencies* (no `DEPENDS`) that generates your file, and add a custom command that depends on this target, mentions that it `OUTPUT`s the file, and doesn't actually do anything (e.g. `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo`). Then mention the output file somewhere (presumably you have it as a source of a library or executable). (You can also use `ALL` for the custom target, but I'm assuming that some code object actually uses the output file, so you'd want said code object to depend on the output file.)

Ideally you'd want to refrain from modifying the file unless something actually changes, or else you won't ever get a no-op build. (How to do this is left as an exercise for the reader.)