# cmake add_custom_command not working

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I am trying to run `gperf` from a `cmake` file.

I created a very minimal `CMakeLists.txt` below.

When I run it by

```
$ cmake .
$ make
```

It does not create the `example.hpp` file

What could be problem with the below `CMakeLists.txt`?

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )

function(gperf_generate_new source target)

        add_custom_target(${target} echo "Creating ${target}")

        add_custom_command(
                SOURCE ${source}
                TARGET ${target}
                COMMAND gperf -L c++ ${source} > ${target}
                OUTPUTS ${target}
                DEPENDS ${source}
                )

endfunction()

gperf_generate_new(command_options.new.gperf example.hpp)
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354473/cmake-add-custom-command?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696872/cmake-add-custom-command-that-is-executed-on-every-build?rq=1) Q/As. Likely your question is a duplicate.

Comment: Problem with your CMakeLists.txt file is that you use incorrect options for `add_custom_command`: `SOURCE` option is completely unrelated to this command, `OUTPUTS` should be `OUTPUT` and shouldn't be mixed with `TARGET` option (`OUTPUT` and `TARGET` are used for *different flows* of this command). **CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#section_Commands) precisely describes command's signatures**, no needs to guess which additional option can take this or that command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files, produced by *source-files generators*(like `gpref`) are rarely needed as standalone. Instead, these source files are usually used for creating executables or libraries inside a project.

So, standard pattern of using source-file generators in the CMake looks like:

```
# Call add_custom_command() with appropriate arguments for generate output file
# Note, that *gperf* will work in the build tree,
# so for file in the source tree full path should be used.
function(gperf_generate_new input output)
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${output}
        COMMAND gperf -L c++ ${input} > ${output}
        DEPENDS ${input}
        COMMENT "Generate ${output}" # Just for nice message during build
    )
endfunction()

# Generate *example.hpp* file ...
gperf_generate_new(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/command_options.new.gperf example.hpp)

# ... for use it in executable
add_executable(my_program ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/example.hpp <other sources>)
```

If you want only to test whether `example.hpp` is generating, instead of `add_executable()` use

```
add_custom_target(my_target
    ALL # Force target to be built with default build target.
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/example.hpp
)
```

Note, that linkage between `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target` is expressed using same filename in their `OUTPUT` and `DEPENDS` options correspondingly. With such link order of these commands is insignificant (but both commands should be called from the same `CMakeLists.txt` script).

Comment: on my build system it worked only when I changed it to
add_custom_target(my_target
        ALL # Force target to be built with default build target.
            DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/example.hpp
    )

Comment: For me it works unmodified, but CMake doesn't explicitely document usage of relative paths in `DEPENDS` option for `add_custom_target`. I have fixed my post.