# CMake custom command called twice

Tags: cmake

Why `version.cmake` are called twice in the setup detailed bellow? How do I correct this to call it just one time?

Details: The objective is to call `version.cmake` in every build **once**, regardless of any dependency (this trick was adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32062884/8952375)). This module verify the current git version and if it differs from a previous `version.cpp` file, it write a new file. The `version.cpp` are a dependency of the main program `test.cpp` and are linked together. This way, if the version stay the same, nothing need to be compiled or linked, if differs, it get recompiled and relinked with the main cpp. A reconfiguration isn't needed.

Note: To make this more easy to explain/reproduce, and be more focused in the related problem, the `version.cmake` bellow was greatly simplified, not depending of git. It just write a new `version.cpp` every time it is called.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.cmake
    DEPENDS dummy_always_rebuild
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT dummy_always_rebuild
    COMMAND true > /dev/null
)

add_library(libversion OBJECT
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp
)

add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE libversion)
```

**version.cmake**:

```
message("version.cmake called")

# (not showed here) get sw version, **IF** it differs from existing 'version.cpp', write a new file:
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp" "const char* version=\"xx.yy.zz\";")
```

**test.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
extern const char* version;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        std::cout << "version=" << version << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Console output for the `make` command (after a `cmake` run). Observe that `version.cmake` are called twice:

```
[ 20%] Generating dummy_always_rebuild
[ 40%] Generating version.cpp
version.cmake called
Scanning dependencies of target libversion
[ 40%] Generating dummy_always_rebuild
[ 40%] Generating version.cpp
version.cmake called
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libversion.dir/version.cpp.o
[ 60%] Built target libversion
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable test
[100%] Built target test
```

Setup info: Linux OS, cmake version 3.12.0, GNU Make version 4.2.1.

Comment: You need to `touch` the output `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp` in any case.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov Why? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: If a custom command output file will be older than CMakeLists.txt then this custom command will be executed every time you run the build.

Comment: I oversimplified `version.cmake` here. In my actual configuration, `version.cpp` is updated/touched only when the GIT revision is changed. Even when `version.cpp` it is not updated/touched, `version.cmake` is called twice every time I run make.