# CMakeList esp-idf run python script each build

Tags: eclipse, cmake, esp32, esp-idf, cmake-custom-command

I am using ESP32 with eclipse esp-idf plugin. It uses CMake to build the application. I want to run on each build a python script. In standard C eclipse project I do using prebuild steps in project configuration. In case of esp-idf project there is no such option. Is it possible to run this python script before each build?

Comment: See https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-96_non_ant_pjs.htm

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but there are some problems with this solution. First is that output on the console is only from the second run program. So when I set to run first my python script than CDT Builder, I got in console only output from the CDT. When I reverse the order to run firstly CDT and than my script I got output only from my python script. Another problem is that each build always changes my launch configuration to my python script and I have to change it back to my working project.

Comment: I have finally found the solution using cmake:
[Running custom script on each build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920072/how-to-always-run-command-when-building-regardless-of-any-dependency)